# Blank attribute table after applying filter in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, sql, select-by-attribute

I am completely new to QGIS and am looking for help with filtering OpenStreetMap data.

When I applied a filter to the vector layer using the clause `"building" is not null` and test it, prompt shows me returned 4000 rows but map display area is blank. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried NULL all uppercase?

Comment: yes, I tried all combinations of uppercase and lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the feature you applied after filtering is just outside the display extent of the map. You can try right clicking on the layer and selecting zoom to layer. If you have already done this, but still do not show it, then it may be for other reasons.